# My browser will not display special characters

Tags: html, css

I have linked my HTML code here. Why is it that when I open this file (locally) on my computer, some special characters will not show. For example, imagine I wrote this code:

nwqidn wqindiwq dwqin <wiqndiw

When opened, the browser will not display the last line of gibberish (anything after and including the less-than symbol). I understand that the browser might have some confusion about when to end the tag, but surely the google browser is advanced enough to know the difference between the closing p tag and a random "<" symbol. I know that I can use the Unicode for "<" and it will display, but I'm trying to find a different solution. Is there any special something that I can put (maybe as metadata?) in my HTML file in order to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's my entire code of the page below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset="utf-8">

<title>Test</title>
</head>


<body>
<p> dniqwn qwnid wqudn <inwqd </p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&lt;` for 'less than' and `&gt;` for 'greater than' to insert < and > into html.

Otherwise, as you say, the browser will think you're opening a tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset="utf-8">

<title>Test</title>
</head>


<body>
<p> dniqwn qwnid wqudn &lt;inwqd </p>

</body>
```

Comment: Right, I know there is a code for each special character that I can insert into the file in order for it to display without anything malfunctioning. But for example, what would a blog poster do? Or someone who needs to write a news article and have it display on a news website (like cnn.com or foxnews.com). I doubt they write or even know about the code for "<", yet I'm sure they can type "<" and have it display on the article or whatever. So what is occurring there? Is there an automatic replacement of the "<" to "&lt;" before the article is uploaded?

Comment: In those situations the raw user input is processed and converted to put it in the form it needs to be to display properly. 
Exactly how that gets done depends on the context. That's why you can type < > in this text box and submit it without trouble. If you're working directly within an HTML document, you can't. Depending on which editor you use you might be able to set something up to automatically change it for you.